# How to save a .xltm file to .xlsm with OpenXML?

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

Ive been using the OpenXmlPackage.SaveAs to save my template files in to excel (.xltx to .xlsx) But when it comes to a macro enabled .xltm the file gets corrupt when saving to .xlsm

I have been reading in the help sections for this API and various threads online but i couldnt find anything covering this so i could get it working.

```cs
//open the excel using openxml sdk  
using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.CreateFromTemplate(fileOpen))
{
    doc.SaveAs(fileClose);
}
```

"Excel cannot open the file 'filename.xlsx' because the file format for the file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

Anyone out there that have a idea regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some very basic differences in the file identification parts of the Open XML Package, specifically in the top-level "Rels". Take a xlsx and save it as an xslt, making no other changes. Open the first in the OPen XML SDK Productivity Tool and then use "compare" to see how the original differs from the changed file. You'll also get the code necessary to create the second from the first.

Comment: I see, but it gives me loads of code? Im not sure what to use since im completley new in to Open XML.

Comment: If the *compare* gives you loads of code, then doing it probably needs it. The *compare* gives the code required to turn the original file into the second one. I've never looked at the code for Excel, only for Word, but it should be similar... and it wasn't that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do the trick.

```
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(sDocpath + inputPath);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
   stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
   using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
     {
     // Change from template type to workbook type
     spreadsheetDoc.ChangeDocumentType(DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.MacroEnabledWorkbook);
     }
   File.WriteAllBytes(dirPath + outputPath, stream.ToArray());
}
```